# Not receiving mouseMoveEvent without holding mouse button

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to implement a hover functionality where I repaint the item when I hover specific areas on my item.

```
class TestItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestItem(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr) : QQuickItem(parent)
    {
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
    }

protected:
    // QQuickItem interface
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        qDebug() << "mouseMoveEvent()" << event->buttons() << event->x() << event->y();
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        qDebug() << "mousePressEvent()" << event->buttons() << event->x() << event->y();
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        qDebug() << "mouseReleaseEvent()" << event->buttons() << event->x() << event->y();
    }
};
```

However, using this class I dont receive any "mouseMoveEvent()" outputs on terminal when I move the cursor over my item. It only works when holding any mousebutton.

How to archieve this without forcing the user to hold any mouse button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could solve it on my own, the problem was I was listening for the wrong events. The correct event would have been `hoverMoveEvent()`.

Using the following class, I got the correct output:

```
class TestItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestItem(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr) : QQuickItem(parent)
    {
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    }

protected:
    // QQuickItem interface
    void hoverEnterEvent(QHoverEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        qDebug() << "hoverEnterEvent()" << event->posF();
    }

    void hoverMoveEvent(QHoverEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        qDebug() << "hoverMoveEvent()" << event->posF();
    }

    void hoverLeaveEvent(QHoverEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        qDebug() << "hoverLeaveEvent()" << event->posF();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, mouse events will only fire if a mouse button is held.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop

Use like so:

```
    explicit TestItem(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr) : QQuickItem(parent)
    {
        setMouseTracking(true); /* <-- */
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
    }
```

Alternatively, you can implement the hover events